# Is it okay to use string as your ID in a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have designed my database and I use varchar to make unique name. I made a table products and each product has a product code, and this code is unique, it cannot be repeated and mostly this is my primary key in parent table. The idea is, for example I have a candle, and candles have different colors so a different product, I am able to make product name distinct by its product code. I didn't use or name a table as an indexable id which is of type int and that it auto_increments when new item is inserted. I just used the unique code as an indexer to my other tables on foreign keys.

I do not know if this is of great idea, I am very new to PHP MySQL and I got some problem when it comes to inserting values into different tables so I use the product code to link them both. Now I just knew about mysqli_insert_id stuff which could have solve my problem a long time ago.

So can I just use a non-standard row id of string than row id of type int???

Comment: Assuming you have some form of indexing on the table, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: an ID can be whatever you want. It's somewhat more efficient internally to use an int, but most anything that can have a unique index slapped onto it can be used as an ID.

Comment: Does string type Primary keys make index size bulkier compared to that of Int type?

Comment: If you've unique method to identify a Product go with and use it as Primary key. You'll be indexing it anyways.

Comment: I see, strings have huge implications on performance, I think I have to rethink and refactor my database so it can accomodate int indexers. Yeah, that's my problem, how can I do it? How could I know the id if it a_i on the fly? Maybe mysqli_insert_id and its counterparts is the answer? I saw a post which gave a concept of doing so so I just started this question if I am doing the right thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally I would say to use an auto inc ID. Using your product code as an ID / primary key means you can't (or will be harder to) change the product code later on down the line which may cause problems.

To elaborate:

If you end up expanding your database so that your products are linked to various tables, using a product code as your ID means that if you want to change your product code you will have to update each entry in ALL tables. Using an ID that isn't the product code means you just have to update the code in one place (stock table) and the ID's will do the rest as you join the stock table to get the product code.

Comment: If you have a big database with lots of tables then changing the product code means you would have to change a lot of different data in different tables. Using an ID that isn't the product code means you can change the product code in one place. Im not saying you can't update auto inc fields.

Comment: @Asaph He's talking about the value of surrogate keys. Auto-update doesn't matter, what matters is how likely it is that you'll want to update the key. If you can forsee it happening, you can save yourself a lot of pain by following the advice.

Comment: hmmm, I just realize, If I only allow changes of product code from the parent table, I have designed my changes in parent table to cascade down to children would it have problems? The problem you are referring to is on changing product code on child tables? I can see it can update upward the heirarchy.

Comment: If you are going to allow product code changes and you are starting this database design from scratch then it would be wise to use Auto IDs, it will save you work regardless of the implementations you have. Using the product code will mean any tables linking to stock will need updating when changing the product code which IMHO defeats the point of a relational DB.

Comment: Imagine you merge with acme corp and productcode is no longer unique. Use a surrogate key, it's a "ten minute" job

Answer (score 7):

Big disadvantage of string ids is that it make indexes (much) bigger, which could affect performance.

I would keep it simple and go with standard auto increment int.

I also agree with @hd1 and @webnoob answers -- row id should be constant and independent from value which it describes -- classic wrong (in my opinion) row id is American SSN or any other *unique* number assigned by government to man or company.

Answer (score 4):

Any unique [and ideally non-changing] value, group of values can be used as a Key/Primary Key in a database. The main reason that surrogate keys [eg: autoincremented INT columns] are so common in mySQL is because:

1. For a long time foreign keys were a no-go, [InnoDB has become *usable* only recently] and keeping string keys synchronized across several tables without them is a nightmare.
2. An index on a string column has a length, and can be shorter than the column itself. This is so you can keep your indexes compact, but can also cause issue issues. eg: A key on a `name` column with length of 5 collides on names `Tom Cruise` and `Tom Clancy` because the key is `Tom C`.

Comment: Yeah! I have been using InnoDB thus far. I heavily rely on the GUI on xampp to make my task easier without typing in the SQL. I knew this is a bad practice, but hey I do understand the syntax I just have to make my work faster. I found out that I could not change values on indexable/FK rows unless otherwise the value to be replaced exist on the parent table. This really confuses me before, but I always got error that FK fails to update key on child row because of this. But thanks for the heads up about collision, it such a shame I haven't seen that one coming!

Answer (score 2):

The pros and cons of natural vs surrogate keys will continue to be argued about for as long as we have relational databases. I say: do what you like, but if you are going to use a surrogate, try to make sure that, where possible, there is also a way of uniquely identifying rows by means of a natural key.

Comment: Keyword saved on my word bank and I will research of this terms soon.

Answer (score 1):

Strings need to be parsed to be equated (on query, joins, etc). So, there's a performance implication. This means you should avoid it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do it, but just because you can, doesn't mean you **should**. A primary key, in theory, should not have any meaning outside the database. A product code, by definition, has meaning outside the database.

Comment: What "theory" is this? In relational database theory the primary key is supposed to be an intrinsically unique aspect of the data.

Comment: I would not believe that any data coming from outside DB has really unique aspect (i.e. SSN, day of birth of employee child).

Comment: Ooh are we going to have a debate on natural versus surrogate keys?

Comment: If people want to argue that it's nicer _in practice_ to use artificial keys, fine (although, you could try before giving up), but database _theory_ is not ambiguous about it being wrong. I take exception to people writing "it's from theory!" on their white-labeled personal philosophy before handing it to people who don't know better.

Comment: I'm not a purist, but I try real hard to always use a surrogate, simply for the amount of flex they give you. It's a decision you need to make early, and there is a cost or two. I've seen natural key and "this will never change" way too many times to treat use of one as a Primary key with anything but extreme suspicion. I'm a practical bloke at heart.